# Overriding the clean method in a Django model breaks other validations?

Tags: django, validation, django-models, django-admin

Assume I have a simple model in `models.py` that is intended to be edited via Django Admin:

```
class Range(models.Model):
    gt = models.IntegerField('Greater than')
    lt = models.IntegerField('Lesser than')

    def clean(self):
        if self.gt >= self.lt:
            raise ValidationError('Incorrect range')
```

The problem: While the above code does a great job in ensuring the assumption that `gt` is lesser than `lt`, it also breaks other basic validations that Django provides out-of-the-box. If, for example, I enter some non-numeric data for these fields in Django admin, I am presented with debug messages that span several screens:

[image]

If I remove the overrided `clean(self)` method from the definition of `Range`, this basic validations once again start working properly:

[image]

But of course, now I can enter `Range`s with `gt` greater than `lt`.

I really don't know what I am doing wrong, since I though I was simply following Django documentation, as per https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects

Where is my mistake? How to correctly provide validation for my form?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can run the parent `clean` method first:

```py
class Range(models.Model):
    gt = models.IntegerField('Greater than')
    lt = models.IntegerField('Lesser than')
    
    def clean(self):
        super().clean()
    
        if self.gt >= self.lt:
            raise ValidationError('Incorrect range')
```